# Auto trigger keyboard shortcut on web page load?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts, onload, key-bindings

Is there any way I can simulate the execution of keyboard shortcut on web page load? For example - I need to automatically trigger 'Alt + Ctrl + L' shortcut event on some pages as if the visitor did that (but did not).

Any ideas?

Comment: *"automatically trigger 'Alt + Ctrl + L'"*  What does that do in your IE (just WAG'ing)?  It has no effect in my FF.  *"as if the visitor did that (but did not)."* Sounds down-right evil.  What is the use-case for this?  What feature does it provide the end user? *"Any ideas?"* Describe the goal you are trying to achieve, rather than the strategy with which you are attempting to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your prompt answer. The above shortcut calls for SimpleModal Login plugin window in my wordpress blog. I want that lightbox window with login box to appear to unregistered users automatically.

Comment: It can probably be called using JS.  Little if anything to do with Java.

Comment: Ops, sorry. Here - you can test it here if you wish: www. imateponudu dot com/oglasite-akciju/

Comment: Test what?  Nothing happens when I visit that page and type Alt-Ctrl-l (or Alt-Ctrl-Shift-l).

Comment: It would be great fun if this was possible.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - I did some tweaking in the meantime... Alt-Ctrl-L should work now on the page.

Comment: OK I see the dialog now.  What does this have to do with Java?  There are JavaScripts in that page.  They are what (I guess) binds the key codes to the action.  But the important thing is the action they call, find that function, and call it on page load.  It's been a while since I've dealt with `onLoad` events and am a little hazy.  In any case, re-tagging as JavaScript.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for having look at it. Also thanks for the tip: the function that should be called is '$('.simplemodal-login').trigger('click.simplemodal-login');' but I have no idea how to write proper Jquery code to call this modal dialog. Anyway, onLoad is a key word here, I'll try and Google it. Many thanks.

Comment: And here we go (bingo): '$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.simplemodal-login').trigger('click.simplemodal-login');
});' It works like charm!